# What is the equivalent of a Windows batch file on the Mac operating system?

Tags: java, windows, macos, batch-file

I'm porting a Java program involving ProcessBuilder and batch files from Windows to Mac, and the Windows-specific app has the following code.

The batch file is as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal

start /wait java BatchWakeMeUpSomehow

if errorlevel 1 goto retry
echo Finished successfully
exit


:retry
echo retrying...
start /wait java BatchWakeMeUpSomehow
```

And this is the Java code :

```
public class WakeMeUpSomehow {
    static class Message extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            try {

                while(true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Hello World from run");

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Message());
            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What i need is  - how do you create a similar batch file on Mac OS ( which is linux- based ) .  I understand that there aren't batch files on Mac's.

Thanks very much for any assistance.

Comment: What you're looking for is a "shell script"

Comment: You need to use shell script.

Comment: 'which is linux- based'.. No.  Mac OS is not Linux based.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446231/how-close-are-mac-os-x-and-bsd-related.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something similar as the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$1
javac $name.java
java $name 
exitCode="${?}"
if [[ $exitCode==0 ]]; then
    echo "ok"
else echo "not ok"
fi
```

The script takes the name of your java as argument, it compiles it and executes it. Finally it gives to you the result status when the execution ends.