# How can I set a thread's CPU affinity in Qt5?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5, affinity

Working with threads in **Qt5**, how can I set a single thread's [CPU affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity)?

I want to specify a mask of available CPU cores that the thread may run under.

In other words, what is the Qt5 equivalent to Posix thread's [`pthread_setaffinity_np()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html) ?

Can I do this for threads managed by `QThreadPool`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually that sort of things is done by extracting the native thread handle and then doing whatever system specific stuff necessary, as no accepted cross-platform API exists for low level thread management.

Indeed, if we inspect the source for the `qthread_unix.cpp` we will see the following:

```
Qt::HANDLE QThread::currentThreadId() Q_DECL_NOTHROW
{
    // requires a C cast here otherwise we run into trouble on AIX
    return to_HANDLE(pthread_self());
}
```

And in `qthread_win.cpp` the implementation will differ in the expected way:

```
Qt::HANDLE QThread::currentThreadId() Q_DECL_NOTHROW
{
    return reinterpret_cast<Qt::HANDLE>(quintptr(GetCurrentThreadId()));
}
```

So, it is responsibility of the application code to do the proper low level actions pertaining to each platform it is expected to run on.

Answer (score 4):

Qt doesn't provide any public APIs for setting processor affinity. There's definitely no way to do this for a `QThreadPool`, which doesn't even provide an API for accessing the `QThread`s within the pool.

For explicitly-created `QThread` objects, you could try using the `QThread::getCurrentThreadId()` function to return a native "handle" to the thread, and then pass that to your system's thread-management library calls. But I would strongly recommend against this. The docs explicitly state:

> **Warning:** The handle returned by this function is used for internal purposes and should not be used in any application code.

If you're building for a specific platform, you might be able to mix calls to your OS's library (e.g., `pthreads`), but that will not be portable and I have no idea if it will work.

Your best bet is probably to manage the CPU affinity of the whole application from the command-line. If you're on Linux, [`taskset`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) is the way to go. For Windows, take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187241/change-affinity-of-process-with-windows-script). Unfortunately, Apple seems pretty determined to prevent users from setting thread affinity, at least from the command line.

Comment: I don't know anything about Mac OS/X except that I remember they based on BSD ([SO: How closely are Mac OS X and BSD related?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3446231/7478597)). Out of curiosity, I googled and found this: [SU: How to set processor affinity on OS X?](https://superuser.com/a/770772).

Comment: @Scheff Yeah, I'm aware of the thread affinity API. But most of the Mach threading code is *really* poorly documented. I've mostly had to dig around in system headers to figure out how to use any of it, which is...annoying.